# Deploying project to Github Pages with Vite and GH-Pages issue

Tags: reactjs, path, github-pages, vite

when I deploy my project to Github pages it goes blank I believe it is because it's path'd weirdly. Instead of being in Game/glb file it is at /glb file, you can see from these [picture](https://imgur.com/a/p7kgOzb) my issue. Would appreciate the help, it is my first time dealing with vite and gh-pages with glb files.

I've read some articles that it has to do with the Public file but can't seem to find the solution